# PHP Frameworks for JQUERY/AJAX Client Mainly for Authentication Process and Database Manipulation. Which one?

Tags: php, jquery, frameworks

I'd like to have "PRO" Php developers advice regarding the framework they use , specially for an application that use "mainly" php as authentication process, connector and db data process in relationship with an Ajax/Jquery Client ... I use Zend Framework , but is that framework the lightest solution for that kind of process ?

In my list i have :

1. Symfony http://symfony.com/get_started
2. Kohana http://kohanaframework.org/

Ok,

Here are further details on what i need :

I'm developing a website that needs these requirements :

Simple login with classic interface and social ones (facebook, twitter).
When user login , he can just change some parameters on his account (pseudo, password and so on).
Then, the only thing he can do is creating what i will call "objects" that have different properties.
These "objects" can then be share with others through a graphical interface.

Nearly everything on the client side will be just displaying these objects with Jquery/Ajax in relashionship with PHP...

So, i just need PHP for oAuth process and datas manipulations...

I'm trying to find the best solutions regarding this little scenario...

For now, i use Zend Framework on Zend server, it works, but seems to be a little bit "heavy" .. so my question is : is there a better 'lightest' way to consider this ?

Dunno if i'm clear :-/ ...

So, thanks in advance !

Comment: Pick a framework by determining what you need it to do, and researching each framework to decide which is the best fit.

Comment: Yes.. sure.. you are right.. it's just what i'm asking for.
What i need is in the subject, so have u an advice ?

Comment: Don't run with scissors.

Comment: ofc not... sorry if i seem to ;) .. seriously, i thought my question wasn't without interest.
I know that i have to pick the one that fit the best my requirements, but in my case, which one do u think is the best ?

Comment: Honestly?  You already got my advice in my first reply, determine what you need and research the frameworks you have available to determine the best fit.  As we don't really know what you need, we can't really offer any solid advice.  I don't like Zend 1.x, but that's personal preference rather than solid advice.

Comment: Ok ... :) thanks.. i've just updated my question trying to be more clear on my needs ... hope it is now . btw thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside agreeing with Gordon, I can see you're just looking for someone to suggest something besides zend.

I would go with Kohana over Symfony because Kohana is much easier to understand out of the box and doesn't require any special setup to work with. It is fast enough to supply you with whatever I assume you need at this level - and by that I mean that if you were building an enterprise level site like ebay you wouldn't be asking this question at all.

You don't need to use the ORM for database interaction but if you decide to it is very easy to understand and will make the development process much faster, even if you don't know the ins and outs of it.

Officially my answer is to agree with Gordon though. If he posts his comment as an answer I will upvote it because you shouldn't just ask the community what they use while providing a tiny list of things you need that almost every site on the planet also uses. It's just too vague.

And yes, I use Kohana all the time. Codeigniter as well if you want another option.

[Limonade](http://limonade-php.github.com/) is another option for very tiny micro-framework. I dislike it for a huge number of reasons but it is not hard to use.

Comment: Okee... thanks Kai... 
To be honnest, first time i ask the community on that site even if i use it a lot ! 
So.. sorry if i seem a little confuse with my request...
OFC yess.. i ask to confirm/unconfirm that the solutions i plan to use are the more suitable and it seems that it's not the good place for that kind of requests..
Btw.. thanks for replying, will give u a ++ when i'll get more better reputation (maybe one day :D ) .. regards